# How to forcefully redirect a user to a certain page properly?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to redirect a user to a certain page if “some_condition” is met. For instance, a user must create an article if there’re no articles created at all. The redirect must happen from all the controllers and actions in them.

I have a plug:

```
defmodule P1 do
  alias Plug.Conn

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(conn, opts) do
    if some_condition do

      Phoenix.Controller.redirect(conn, to: MyApp.Router.Helpers.article_path(conn, :new))
      |> Plug.Conn.halt()
    end
  end
end
```

An issue with this is that

a) it’ll redirect all the requests to “article_path/new”, including ones to js, css, etc … files. Namely, it’ll occur multiple times in a row per one route. Instead of one single redirect, as I want.

b) a page won’t be rendered. It’ll be displayed as an empty page when I redirect a user this way

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to define [different pipelines](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#content) for the different types of content and include this plug only where it belongs.

Somewhat like

```rb
pipeline :authenticate do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  plug :protect_from_forgery
  plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  plug :p1 # yours one
end

scope "/app", AppWeb do
  pipe_through :authenticate

  get "/", ...
  ...
end
```

Comment: that won't work because assets will still be served via `:authenticate` which will cause multiple hits for my plug module `P1`. As before

Comment: Serve assets via `:assets`, I do not get the issue.

Comment: Back to my initial question. In my question there's nothing like `authenticate` and not even anything similar to it. Your solution still won't work for my case. Which is `always redirect to "add article" if conditionNNN`

Comment: That is, implementation-wise my case is different